# HTTP 103 Early Hints: How to diagnose if they are correctly set by Cloudflare and respected by Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cloudflare

For my [cryptocurrency market data website](https://tradingstrategy.ai)

- I have [enabled early hints](https://blog.cloudflare.com/early-hints/) on Cloudlare
- I am generating early hints on [SvelteKit/Vite web server hooks](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/7b2a95093f5dc41ae975d097040ae49b907c253d/src/hooks/index.ts#L52)
- I have verified the presence of `Link` headers in the HTTP reply

```
Link: </fonts3.css>; rel="preconnect", </_app/assets/start-6f5e0715.css>; rel="preconnect", </_app/assets/pages/__layout.svelte-f31b19cc.css>; rel="preconnect", </_app/assets/pages/index.svelte-84a34be8.css>; rel="preconnect"
```

- [I have enabled Chrome command line flag to respect early hints](https://blog.cloudflare.com/early-hints/#testing-early-hints-with-web-page-test)

Now, how do I verify that

- Cloudflare is correctly generating `HTTP/1.1 103 Early Hints`. Can I display this information with `curl` or `wget`?
- Chrome is respecting the early hint - where this is shown in the Performance tab of webr developer tools, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no luck to verify Chrome's response from Chrome's devtool. When I monitor the network traffic, Chrome devtool does not show 103 responses at all. However, I am able to verify the server 103 responses using curl. Here is   a curl output sample:

$ curl -k -v —http2 https://evanella.org

...

- Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
- Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fa7a2009200)

> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: evanella.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*

...

- Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!

< HTTP/2 103

< link: https://evanella.org/; rel=preload;

< link: https://evanella.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/assets/fonts/SourceSerif4Variable-Roman.ttf.woff2; rel=preload; as=font

< link: https://evanella.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/assets/images/flight-path-on-transparent-d.png; rel=preload; as=image

< link: https://evanella.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/style.css?ver=1.1; rel=preload; as=style

< link: https://evanella.org/wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view.min.js?ver=3776ea67846b3bb10fe8f7cdd486b0ba; rel=preload; as=script

...

< HTTP/2 200

< server: h2o/2.3.0-DEV@998a7fb7b

< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

< link: https://evanella.org/wp-json/; rel="https://api.w.org/"

< vary: Accept-Encoding

BTW, I configured my own webserver to generate the 103 early hints responses.

Comment: Here is my troubleshooting thread from Cloudflare community forum https://community.cloudflare.com/t/http-103-early-hints-how-to-diagnose-if-they-are-correctly-set-by-cloudflare-and-respected-by-chrome/345677

Comment: If I recall correctly you need to force Chrome to do Early hints, as it is not available by default (was not available). Also despite this, the Developer Console might not display these (it also does not display some HTTP OPTIONS requests), so double check and then triple check.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa hey, can you clarify how to "force Chrome to do Early Hints"?

im not seeing any results on google to force this feature. Currently on Chrome 106

Comment: Did you check the Cloudflare discussion thread for comments?

Comment: Just checked it out and thank you! Chrome really needs some better release notes. Its like we're just left in the dark to figure this out

Comment: Is https://evanella.org still returning a 103?  I don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This site is an online tool for testing whether Early Hints are being provided:

https://code103.hotmann.de

Comment: Is this detecting the 103 or just outputting headers related to early hints?

Answer (score 1):

In chrome you'd enter this in console:

`performance.getEntriesByName('https://yourwebsite.com/image.jpg')[0].initiatorType`
which will output `link` or `early-hints` respectively (maybe some more values, etc.), which, in case of `early-hints` indicates that certain asset download was initiated by 103 header.

In my case i'm stuck on receiving `link` where `early-hints` are expected. Will update this response if I learn something more during the debug process.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Been trying for a while and not getting early hints as initiator in latest chrome :(